# Is there a way to reduce the stack trace (noise) when using FluentAssertions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, fluent-assertions

I'm using the [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) library in a .dotnet core project.  I really appreciate the easy with which I can read and understand tests with this 'grammar'.

I am developing this project in VSCode; it's actually running out of a Docker container.

For continuous testing I am running from the console window:

```sh
dotnet watch --project ./test-project test
```

When a test fails, I get the complete stack trace in the output.  This can amount to ten or more lines, most of which are directly related to the actual `FluentAssertions` library exception and not the code under test.  This is a lot of noise that I do not need or want.  Primarily, it means I need to remove my attention from the code and deal with scrolling and looking for the details of the failed test.

Is there a way to silence the stacktrace?

Alternately, is there other tooling I can use with VSCode to visualize the errors and not have to use the console output.

For completeless I should also point out that I am using xUnit and the dotnet-test-explorer extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sort of answer - xUnit and the dotnet-test-explorer don't play well out-of-the-box together.

I had to:

- ensure that my assembly name matched the root namespace
- enable the extensions watching

  - `"dotnet-test-explorer.autoWatch": true`
- set the path to the test project

  - `"dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "src/Tests/*.csproj"`
- set the commandline args to get the gutters extension working again

  - `"dotnet-test-explorer.testArguments": "/p:CollectCoverage=true   /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov /p:CoverletOutput=./lcov.info "`

From time to time the `lcov.info` file gets wiped out, not sure of the direct cause, simple enough fix though - delete the 0byte file and refresh the test list.

Gonna try running the `dotnet watch ...` with the generate coverage args from the console while the explorer does it's own thing.

While this doesn't answer the initial question, it does give me a workable solution that I can live with.